# apply() function Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Did anybody cope with this issue?

Code after apply doesn't execute in Internet Explorer

```
originalFocus.apply(this, arguments);
$(document).scrollTop(300);
```

scrollTop doesn't execute at all in IE!

but if put alert() for example it will work

```
originalFocus.apply(this, arguments);
alert('ha');
$(document).scrollTop(300);
```

here is the full code:

```
(function($) {
    var originalFocus = $.fn.focus;
    $.fn.focus = function () {
        if (this.hasClass('no-scroll')) {
            var y = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body).scrollTop;

            originalFocus.apply(this, arguments);
            $(document).scrollTop(y);
        } else {
            return originalFocus.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**ANSWER**

Well, guys, I found a problem - needed to return a function, simple)

```
(function($) {
var originalFocus = $.fn.focus;
$.fn.focus = function () {

    return function() {
        if (this.hasClass('no-scroll')) {
            var y = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body).scrollTop;

            originalFocus.apply(this, arguments);
            window.scrollTo(x, y);
        } else {
            originalFocus.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };

};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What does `originalFocus` do? looks like you're running into a race condition.

Comment: We do not know what sort of plugin you are using Kosmetika. Check the documentation, maybe the .apply() method has a callback function .apply(this, arguments, function() { $(document).scrollTop(300)});

Comment: apply() is native js method, i added full code

Comment: Ah I have an idea - it's just a guess but I'll type it  in as an answer.

Comment: @Kosmetika One issue, you aren't returning `this` in the same way that the original focus method does.

Comment: @Kosmetika do you know what value "y" has when it doesn't work? In the sample code where you wrote that it *does* work (with the alert), you hard-coded 300, but in the "real" code it's a variable. Are you missing the "$" when you try to get the "scrollTop()" there into "y"?

Comment: @Kosmetika All jQuery plugins that aren't fetching some sort of data should always `return this;` at the end so that they can be chained to subsequent jQuery methods.

Comment: @KevinB what do you mean?

Comment: @Pointy i know what `y` has, as I already mentioned it doesnt work only in IE

Comment: @Kosmetika In your if statement, one case returns a value, the other doesn't. Both cases should return the original collection of elements.

Comment: @Kosmetika are you *sure* what the value of "y" is in IE?  Have you added a `console.log(y);` and checked the IE developer tools?

Comment: @Pointy yep, checked it

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, trying to force focus inside an event handler can cause problems. Try doing it in a timer handler:

```
      var this2 = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
        originalFocus.apply(this2, arguments);
      }, 1);
```

Comment: it's not a solution.. the problem is that scrollTop() method is not executed at all. It needs to be executed right AFTER applying original focus. The idea of this code is not to scroll top after focusing an element

Comment: @Kosmetika well try putting the `scrollTop()` call inside the timeout handler too. (Like I said, I'm guessing here, but `.focus()` is tricky.)

Comment: there's no difference)) only to wait some time to execute)

Comment: @Kosmetika well the difference is that the code runs in a separate event loop, after the user-initiated event handler has completed and its default action taken.